# Sp 2013 Records Management Trigger Error

Tags: 2013, records-management

After September 2018 Patch i have been receiving error in records management feature of sharepoint 2013. Below is the error, i looked everything couldn't find anything. Have you guys came across such issue, if yes how did you resolve it?

Thank You

Application error when access /_layouts/routermessage.aspx, Error=Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.IsValidAbsoluteWebUrl(System.String)'.   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.RouterMessagePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    9019959e-0458-9017-bbcf-a65b387f66ec

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Apply October CU update that should fix the Issue